# Reputation for questions that have been edited multiple times

Tags: support, reputation

I am pretty new to Stack Exchange Network and trying to understand how it works. In the Main Ask Ubuntu Site I had asked [this Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/229274/problem-resolving-many-of-the-web-pages). I can see that it has received 15 UpVotes till now. I have also Accepted an Answer for that Question. I had also answered one of the questions for which I received 1 UpVote. So, according to the FAQs, my Reputation should have been (15 * 5 + 2 + 1 * 10 + 1 =) 88. But it shows as 56.

Is there any limit on maximum UpVotes on Question that adds to the Reputation Score? Or, what am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have edited your question at least 10 times, after that amount a post becomes considered volatile (rapidly changing) and will be converted to *community wiki*.

[image]

Community wiki lowers the necessary reputation for other users to edit it - making it easier for other users to help you improve it - but also removes the reputation gain/loss from votes after that point.

So yes, you are getting up votes, they will count for badges, but the reputation you would get otherwise wont be present any more.

For more information on *community wiki* posts please visit the meta section of Stack Overflow about it:

- [What are "Community Wiki" posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts)

Comment: Thank you. As you could see, I had to try a lot of different things in order to solve the issue and hence the question was edited a lot of times. So, what is the best way to incorporate the updates in the Question itself without editing it so many times.

Comment: Some information can be discussed in the comments and transported to an edit only when its relevant and you think it might actually help, other than that you have no control about it. If you need to edit it that much then the conversion to community edit will be actually helpful. Nothing you can do further besides actually contacting the moderators and asking them to fix it.

Comment: If that is the case you can flag it and and explain your reasons.

Comment: (btw, having a look at it, no need to flag)

Comment: Ok, did not see any reason to keep the wiki status and removed it. Not sure if that will affect your present reputation, but future votes should account it.

Comment: I also think that the event of my Accepting the Answer is not accounted for since the Question had become a Community Wiki Post by then. Can you confirm?

Comment: The "present status" section of your post should be an edit in to the accepted answer including all the steps you take to connect / disconnect it correctly. Can you be a chap and remove it form the question and include what you need in to the accepted as answer post?

Comment: (about the accepting the answer) yes, nothing we can do about it.

Comment: Ok. Moving "Present Status" from the "Question" to the "Accepted Answer". Thanks